# codeigniter IDE for mac os x

Tags: php, codeigniter, ide

I'm looking for a codeigniter IDE for mac os x.does it exist a plugin for netbeans for this framework? I found it only for windows. I would found it for auto complete !

Comment: CI is really not that complicated that it warrants a whole new IDE. Use what you already know and work through the CI manual :)

Comment: I wish PHPStorm would work with it better but it's still the best PHP Ide for me when I'm working with CI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An IDE specific for Codeigniter doesn't exist as far as I know, however you can for example extend Eclipse to be able to auto-complete CI functions and methods: [Eclipse CI auto complete](http://www.gostomski.co.uk/codeigniter/getting-full-auto-complete-with-codeigniter-in-eclipse)

If syntax highlighting in a standard text editor is what you are looking for, there are several plugins available for TextMate, for example: [Full Codeigniter Textmate Bundle](http://net.tutsplus.com/freebies/others/full-codeigniter-textmate-bundle/) that will also work excellent with the free [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You can get autocomplete for Codeigniter in Netbeans IDE using the CodeIgniter plugin for Netbeans available at http://kenai.com/projects/nbphpci/pages/Home